# xCode 4.6.3 Wax Framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, lua, xcode4.6

I'm just starting out with Obj-C and I found [Wax](https://github.com/probablycorey/wax) which is great, I can do anything Obj-C lets me but with Lua which I much prefer!

Only problem is, I don't seem to be able to find ANY tutorial on how to add this as a framework to xCode 4.6.3. I get that the location of frameworks/templates is `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/Framework\ \&\ Library` but the structure of the frameworks that exist in there and the Wax framework are very different and dropping the files in there doesn't appear to do anything.

How do I add this framework as a project type to xCode 4.6.3 or is there a more up to date library that bridges Obj-C and Lua?

Comment: https://github.com/probablycorey/wax/wiki/Installation .. looks like they advise against xcode 4 + :/

Comment: It does but with the dev centre down I can't get xCode 3 and I would really like to use Wax *sigh*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is actually a framework:

1. Select your project from the file navigator pane at the left edge
2. Select the build target to which you want to add the framework from the left edge of the main pane
3. Select "Build Phases" from the top edge of the main pane
4. Expand the "Link Binary With Libraries (# items)" section in the main pane
5. Click the "+" at the bottom of the list of frameworks
6. Click "Add Other…"
7. Locate the Framework bundle in the file selector
8. Click "Open"

This will add a reference to the framework to your project and ensure that the binaries you make include it; it will not copy the files into your project. You can of course copy it into your project and then locate that copy in step 7.

It may just work if you drag the Framework bundle into the list of frameworks after step 4.